# How do I use the Contentful api data with React Context API (useContext in particular)?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

I'm trying to use a database I set up in a headless cms known as contentful.  The problem is, all the tutorials I watched uses Class components to handle state.  I learned useContext for the Context API method, which I find to be more appealing and less of a headache.  I know how to request data from conetextful, but I don't know how to use the data outside of the use of a Class component.  I suppose one question I could ask is whether it's even possible to use contentful with an object or function component?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'w3-css';
import {BsyndContext} from './context/bsyndContext';
import Client from './Contentful';

Client.getEntries().then(res => console.log(res.items))

ReactDOM.render(
<BsyndContext.Provider value={"data here"} > 
 <Router> 
    <App />
    </Router>
  </BsyndContext.Provider>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BsyndProvider` wrapper component and inside it, make api call(in useEffect) and get your content and store it in the state. Pass the content to `value` prop.

```js
import Client from './Contentful';
export default const BsyndContext = React.createContext({});


export const BsyndProvider = (props) => {
    const [value,setValue] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        Client.getEntries().then(res => setValue(res.items))
    }, []);

    return (
      <BsyndContext.Provider value={value}>
        {props.children}
      </BsyndContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Wrap your application inside the `BsyndContext.Provider`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'w3-css';
import {BsyndProvider} from './context/bsyndContext';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BsyndProvider> 
    <Router> 
        <App />
    </Router>
  </BsyndProvider>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Use context(your content) in your component like this:

```js
function App() {
  const myContent = useContext(BsyndContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {myContent.Heading}
    </div>
  );
}
```